# OMNET++: How do I send a message to a specific node based on probability?

Tags: omnet++

I want to make a simulation such that node 1 has a chance to send its message to node 2 or node 3 based on a given probability, and node 2 should do the same. However, if node 3 receives the message at anytime, then the message is deleted. I tried to make it myself, but it is not working how as I planned. Out1 is an output that goes to either node 1 or 2, while Out2 is an output that goes to node 3. When the message starts at node 1 and it goes to node 3 first, then the message gets properly deleted, but other times it will immediately pop up that there are no more events and that the simulation is completed. I attached my node's cc files, and I am sure the other connections and stuff are correct. Any advice would be much appreciated, I'm still very new to omnet++. Thanks!

```
#include "nodes.h"

Define_Module(Nodes);

void Nodes::initialize()
{
prob1 = .9;
if(strcmp("node1", getName()) == 0){
    if (uniform(0, 1) > prob1){
        EV << "Sending initial message\n";
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("hw4Msg");
        send(msg, "out1");
        }
    else {
        EV << "Sending initial message\n";
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("hw4Msg");
        send(msg, "out2");
    }
}}

void Nodes::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
     counter ++;
     if((counter == 1)&&(strcmp("node3", getName()) == 0)) {
         EV << getName() << "'s counter is " << counter << ", meaning ";
         EV << getName() << " has captured the packet. The message will now be deleted.";
         delete msg;
                   }
    prob2 = .9;
    if(strcmp("node1", getName()) == 0) {
        if (uniform(0, 1) > prob2) {
            EV << getName() << " Received message " << msg->getName() << " ,sending it out again\n";
            EV << getName() << "'s counter is " << counter;
            send(msg, "out1");
        }
        else {
            EV << getName() << " Received message " << msg->getName();
            send(msg, "out2");
        }}
    if(strcmp("node2", getName()) == 0) {
         if (uniform(0, 1) < prob2) {
             EV << getName() << " Received message " << msg->getName() << " ,sending it out again\n";
             EV << getName() << "'s counter is " << counter;
             send(msg, "out1");
                    }
         else {
             EV << getName() << " Received message " << msg->getName();
             send(msg, "out2");
           }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing from your model: how you intend to generate packets. In your current code, you generate a single message (in the `initialize()` method in `node1`) and then send that towards other nodes. Once it finds its way to `node3` the message is deleted and there is no more events for the simulation to simulate, so it stops.

Otherwise, it cannot **immediately** finish as the first message either goes first to `node3` and gets deleted there in the next event, or it goes to `node2` where it is forwarded to either `node1` or `node3` according to your code.

**Unless** you have mistyped the `node2` name in your NED file. But either way, you should single step this in Qtenv and see each events one by one.

As a side note, this scenario can (almost) fully modeled using the modules from the `samples/queueinglib`, (a Source, Sink and a Classifier module). I highly recommend to take a look at that sample.

Comment: An additional advice: It is not advised to program the behavior of multiple node types in a single class (using if (getName== "xxx"). You should have separate C++ classes for the Source, RandomRouter and Sink functionality. If you happen to have getName() == "modulename" in your code, then you do not do it the 'right' way.